# Add a drop-down menu in a NodeGroup

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor

I personally really like NodeGroups. However, I would really like to be able to add a drop-down menu in a NodeGroup, like a normal shader node. I know this is possible with Python, but I'm not really too thrilled about trying that.

I would be hoping for something that functions roughly like this:

[image]

Comment: As you probably already know, it is not possible at the moment, groups just don't do that. Maybe in future versions of blender.

Comment: @David Yeah, I was kind of afraid of that.

Comment: You can make multiple groups with the variations and select them from the dropdown menu of the group node.

Comment: @Denis I could. But I have like 20 groups.